# Node Js call back / promise/ return

Tags: node.js, callback, return

I am kind of new to this node js and went through many explanations, tried many solutions but still cant get my head wrapped around the function call backs.

```js
//app.js file
var dashboardfunc = require('./models/admindashboard');

app.get("/dashboard/:id?", function(req, res) {
 console.log("we are here in dashboard")
 var data = {id: req.params.id};
 console.log(data)

 dashboardfunc.productlist().then(function(results){
  console.log("i am here now ....")
  console.log(results)
 }).catch(function(err){
  if(err){
   console.log(err)
  }
 })
  
});


//admindashboard.js file
//I tried many other alterations like using call back etc. 
// i want the damn results to be back to the app.js and use that 
//
function productlist(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var param = [data.id];
        var sql = 'select * from product where seller_id=?';
        console.log(param)
        pool.query(sql, param, function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                if (results === undefined) {
                    reject(new Error("Error rows is undefined"));
                }
                else {
                    console.log("we got here in productlist")
                    
                    console.log(results)
            
                    return results;                    
                }
            }
        })
    })
}


module.exports = productlist;
```

<--Result -->
Rb-v2 started !!!
we are here in dashboard
{ id: '23' }
TypeError: dashboardfunc.productlist is not a function

Question is why it is so hard to get the results back , and why it needs to be so complicated to call a function , get the return data. Along with that whats the deal with callback v/s promise ( yeah I read almost all post in it still my naive brain cant process it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these small fixes for the start:

1. `admindashboard.js` exports the only function, but `app.js` tries to use it as a property of an object. You need either this type of export:

```js
module.exports = { productlist };
```

or this using:

```js
dashboardfunc().then
```

2. The argument in the imported function call is missing. Try `dashboardfunc(data).then` instead of mentioned `dashboardfunc.productlist().then`.
3. `resolve` callback is not used in `productlist()` function. Use it to return the data from the promise: `resolve(results);` instead of `return results;`.
4. Be consistent in error handling. Use:

```js
           if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            else {
                if (results === undefined) {
                    reject(new Error("Error rows is undefined"));
                }
```

instead of:

```js
           if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                if (results === undefined) {
                    reject(new Error("Error rows is undefined"));
                }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I understood the concept as well for getting the data back. Any details you can share to make me understand promise  ( which use catch, then , reject , resolve v/s callback v/s return .

Comment: You can try these 3 sections of the very comprehensive books: [Asynchronous programming (background)](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_async.html), [Promises for asynchronous programming](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html), and [Async functions](http://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_async-functions.html).

Comment: @HorseLearner Also, you can read and watch some materials about event loop to grasp the overall concept: [Understanding Asynchronous JavaScript](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff), [The Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/), and [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).